# R - Get average values of steps in line chart

Tags: r

Consider this data

```
#Create the dataframe
values <- c(0, 0, 0, rep(30, 59), 0, rep(14, 20), 0, rep(24, 63), 0, 0 )
df <- data.frame(Samples = 1:length(values), Value = values)
#Add noise
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
noise <- rnorm(length(values), mean = 0, sd = 1)  # Generating random noise
df$Value <- df$Value + noise  # Adding noise to the values`

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(y = Value, x = Samples)) +
geom_line(color = "red", size = 1)
```

[image]

I would like to get the mean and SD of each step. They can be of different widths and heights.

I tried calculating the rolling standard deviation then detect the maximas then measure average values between maximas of SD but due to the difference in length of the steps I was unsuccesfull to accuratelly detect the start and end of steps.

Comment: Thanks, for this test data, your suggestion makes 7 steps (the 3 obvious ones plus 2 at the beginning and 2 at the end). How would you suggest dealing with that, as every single value below your threshold becomes a step?

Comment: I've fleshed out in an answer below to trigger a new step whenever we go from a flagged value to an unflagged one.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  arrange(Samples) %>%
  mutate(flag = Value < 5,
         step = cumsum(lag(flag, 1, FALSE) & !flag)) %>%
  filter(!flag) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(Value), 
            sd = sd(Value),
            from = min (Samples),
            to = max(Samples), 
            .by = step) -> df_sum

ggplot(df, aes(y = Value, x = Samples)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = from, xmax = to,
                ymin = avg-sd, ymax = avg+sd),
            alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            data = df_sum) +
  geom_line(color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = from, xend = to,
                   y = avg, yend = avg),
               data = df_sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
If I wanted to exclude the n first and n last points of each step how would you suggest doing it? This is for when the limits of the steps are not that clean